# How to chunk the bundle.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have created a project using react and flux architecture. Need to chunk  the bundle.js file because by combining all the files it is creating a huge js file of 4mb which is causing problem in downloading on slow network so how to chunk the js file so that only the required libraries are included when a page opens
I am using webpack 1.x

my directory structure is

[image]

webpack.config.js file

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: ''
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      // names: ["app", "subPageA"]
      // (choose the chunks, or omit for all chunks)

      children: true,
      // (use all children of the chunk)

      async: true,
      // (create an async commons chunk)

      // minChunks: 3,
      // (3 children must share the module before it's separated)
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: /\.useable\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.useable\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader/useable!css-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.png$/,
      loaders: ["url-loader?mimetype=image/png"]
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
    }]
  }
};
```

server.js file

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(3000, 'localhost', function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

index.html file

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" />
  <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need a particular module, that is not required on the initial load you can use

```
require.ensure(["module-a", "module-b"], function() {
  var a = require("module-a");
  // ...
});
```

That way it only gets loaded when you need it, thus decreasing your bundle size.

If you use routes and react-router you can use per route code splitting as described in this article
http://moduscreate.com/code-splitting-for-react-router-with-es6-imports/

Comment: Your code doesn't reveal any js of your application to make suggestions. But common use cases for code splitting is when you scroll the content 'below the fold' so you put a 'below the fold' content inside require ensure. Or when a user clicks some button and it causes some component to appear on the screen with its big logic. In React though you usually handle code splitting with react router splitting. But you also can load third party libraries through require ensure.

Answer (score 1):

Im my experience, typically with webpack-optimize-chunk-plugin, you split your projects code into a vendor.js and a bundle.js. like this:

```
module.exports = {
   entry:{
       vendor: ["react", "react-dom"], // list all vender libraries here
       app: ['./path/to/entry.js']
   },
   output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, './public'),
       filename:'bundle.js'
   },
   plugins: [
       new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
       new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.js")
   ]
}
```

So this would output a bundle.js and a vendor.js. I haven't seen webpack-optimize-chunk-plugin used in the way you described. (it would be very cool if possible).

Also I would check out all the other webpack optimization plugins to also help with the over all file size. (i.e. DedupePlugin, UglifyJsPlugin, OccurenceOrderPlugin...). More info [here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization). Also [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-commons-chunks) is an example of multi entry point that you may find helpful. Best of luck.